# How to use automator to create a service which converts an ebook (using calibre commands)

Tags: terminal, automator, books, file-conversion

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to right-click on an `.epub` file and convert it to a `.mobi` file. Currently (thanks to calibre command tools) I can to the following within the terminal

```
ebook-convert test.epub test.mobi
```

So  the fist file name `test.epub` is the original, existing file, and the second file name `test.mobi` is that it will be converted to.

Is it possible to create a service from automator which could allow we to right-click on the original `test.mobi` file and then just convert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open Automator, choose the service template, change "Service receives selected" to "files or folders", add a Run Shell Script action, change "Pass input" to "as arguments", and change the command to:

```
for f;do /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert "$f" "${f%.*}.mobi";done
```

[image]

Or if you add

```
2mobi() {
  for f; do
    /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert "$f" "${f%.*}.mobi"
  done
}
```

to a shell configuration file like `~/.bash_profile`, you can run `2mobi /path/to/file.epub` in a shell.